Why not UTC offsets instead of a huge list global timezones?
I know many people try to support multiple time zones when building a SaaS app for example and one example is like a golang app that need to support multiple timezones
standard is store time in DB in UTC and then allow users to select from a huge list of global timezones using the global timezone database like IANA (https://www.iana.org/time-zones) for example
there is even a golang package https://pkg.go.dev/time/tzdata that allows to manage these
BUT why not just use the UTC offsets?
so you just support offsets like
UTC+5
UTC-6
For example you capture many timezones that way like
Here are some timezones that have a UTC offset of UTC+5:
Asia/Ashgabat
Asia/Aqtobe
Asia/Atyrau
Asia/Karachi
Asia/Qyzylorda
Asia/Tashkent
Asia/Tbilisi
Indian/Maldives
Indian/Mauritius

list for UTC-6
America/Belize
America/Costa_Rica
America/El_Salvador
America/Guatemala
America/Honduras
America/Managua
America/Regina
America/Swift_Current
America/Tegucigalpa
America/Chicago (Central Time Zone in the United States)
Pacific/Easter (Easter Island Time)
Canada/Central (Central Time Zone in Canada)

and one can do something like this
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// ConvertTime converts a time from UTC to the specified timezone offset.
func ConvertTime(t time.Time, offset int) time.Time {
    return t.Add(time.Duration(offset) * time.Hour)
}

func main() {
    // Timestamp stored in the database (in UTC).
    dbTime := time.Now().UTC()

    // User's timezone offset (in hours, e.g., UTC+5 or UTC-6).
    userOffset := -6

    // Convert the timestamp to the user's timezone.
    userTime := ConvertTime(dbTime, userOffset)

    // Display the timestamp in the user's timezone.
    fmt.Printf("Timestamp in user's timezone: %s\n", userTime.Format(time.RFC3339))
}



offsets can change

https://www.zainrizvi.io/blog/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time-zones/

yeah for the simplicity, i may have to compromise having users update the timezone when they need to :) else one can go crazy trying to support everyones timezones. great link to article, thanks

i may follow this from your article link  Forget time zones, use the raw UTC offset W3's international standard gave up on the notion of time zones and declared that engineers should only store a timestamp's raw UTC offset.

@uberrebu: Right, only store a timestamp in UTC, or with UTC offset.  But if you're trying to communicate with a human user, they probably don't want to have to work out the conversion from UTC to local time, especially for a time in the past or future when the UTC offset in their location may not be the same as it is today.  So you want to convert to and from the stored UTC value for human input and output.

yeah issue is trying to support all the timezones, the list is huge, so really depends how much importance is having user get their time right or just let the user face the problem to ensure they get their time right by updating themselves. but something to decide about

People were okay with manually resetting their clocks for daylight time in the 1990s.  In the 2020s, not so much.

Sometimes it is important to distinguish 3am from 3pm.

"one can go crazy trying to support everyones timezones" What do you mean by this @uberrebu ? The list of timezones is long, sure, but well defined and extremely static. Plus, your OS will maintain the list for you; if that doesn't work for you (eg. very stripped down docker image) than you can use the tzdata package that does the same thing. I wouldn't "go crazy" having to deal with that. :)

America/Chicago isn't UTC-6 right now, it's UTC-5, because daylight savings time came into effect a few weeks ago.
Suppose your app had an appointment reminder feature.  Back in February, a user in Chicago installed your app, and specified their time zone as UTC-6.  They entered an appointment for April 1 at 10:00 AM local time, and so your app recorded 16:00 UTC.  But when your app gives them a reminder at 16:00 UTC on April 1, it will actually be 11:00 AM according to the clocks in Chicago, and your user will be an hour late for their appointment.
But if you record the time zone as America/Chicago, then 10:00 AM on February 1 becomes 16:00 UTC, while 10:00 AM on April 1 becomes 15:00 UTC.
A time zone specifies not just the offset from UTC for right now, but also for all past times (often back to 1900 or so) and future times (assuming no policy changes).  So America/Chicago will be UTC-5 from the second Sunday in March to the first Sunday in November, and UTC-6 otherwise.  But if you attempt to convert a time that was between the years 1987 and 2006, then it will be UTC-5 from the first Sunday in April to the last Sunday in October.  Or between 1975 and 1986, when it will be UTC-5 from the last Sunday in April to the last Sunday in October.  Et cetera.
On the other hand, if you use America/Guatemala, it will be UTC-6 year round, because Guatemala doesn't observe daylight saving time.  Unless you attempt to convert a date in the summer of 2006, 1991, or 1983, or the winter of 1973-1974, when there were brief experiments with moving to UTC-5 as daylight savings time for part of the year.
The tzdb project is a remarkable undertaking to keep track of not only the current time zones, but also historical ones, and to keep it updated as various jurisdictions make unpredictable changes to their time zone policy, for practical or political reasons.

you mentioned tzdb project, is that similar to the IANA database i mentioned? https://www.iana.org/time-zones
issue is that database has like 600 unique timezones or something like that, that is insane list to support in an app.

@uberrebu: Yes, same project.  But the point of the database (and the package that contains it) is that you the programmer don't have to do the work to support 600 time zones yourself; just use the package.

yeah but my frontend will find a way to manage list of 600 timezones to select from :) but yeah i think programmatically supporting using the database is way to go, and i might reluctantly have to just do that, thanks

"manage list of 600 timezones" - are you sure you need to do this? Most operating systems allow the user to configure their timezone, and honoring that choice is often the right option (i.e. time.Local, similar functionality is available through the browser if your interface is web based). Sometimes you do need to ask; if so, watch out for the GMT zones (e.g. Etc/GMT-12) because the sign is probably not what users will expect.
